# Remove the keyword from url using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, tomcat

How to remove "specific" keyword from url...keyword may come on 2,3rd or 4th position after ".com"

For example:

I want to remove keyword "mobile" from below urls

`http://www.mysites.com:8083/robert/projects/google/mobile/india/en/
http://www.mysites.com:8083/projects/google/mobile/india/en/
http://www.mysites.com/mobile/india/en/`

Comment: so you want "http://www.mysites.com:8083/robert/projects/google/india/en/" in the place of "http://www.mysites.com:8083/robert/projects/google/mobile/india/en/" ?

Comment: Yes Amit..I want like that

Comment: Didn't you ask this question yesterday as well?

Comment: Also, tomcat server does not accept htaccess files for its directives.

Comment: Its possible because below code is working for me.. RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/page1/?(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L].       http://www.example.com/pages/page1/test1/test2 out put will be  http://www.example.com/pages/test1/test2

Comment: But i want to remove test1 from url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/mobile/(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]
```